# Rails - Multiple new by array of values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I wanna do something like this:
Let's say I have a array of users names ["John", "Mary"], etc...
and I wanna create a array with new User records, where name attribute is initialized by those values. What is the easiest way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer by myself:

```
["john", "mary"].map{|u| User.new(name: u)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass your array into this method:

```
def create_users(names):
  users = []
  names.each do |name|
    u = User.create(:name => name)
    users << u
  end
  users
end
```

This:

- takes an array of names in
- creates an empty array to hold the created users
- creates a user for each name and adds the user to the array
- returns the array

Comment: give an upvote but I wanted a simple syntax, like my own answer I just posted... thanks!